# Can I use both Python 2 and Python3 interchangeably in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just need to update code to python 3 since python 2.7 will soon stop being supported. Want to know if I can install Python 3 without screwing up my current 2.7 code?

Comment: Python 2.x is already 5 months out of support

Comment: Here are some step by step instructions: https://datascience.com.co/how-to-install-python-2-7-and-3-6-in-windows-10-add-python-path-281e7eae62a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have more than one version of python on your machine and you can even use any one of them whenever you need it. (In case you need Python2 for some old projects)
In order to that, first you need to have both python version installed and added to PATH variable, then you can go to the root folder of your python2.7 and there you will see a python.exe file which is used as the interpreter, you can just change that file's name to python2 or something and you now you can compile by using `python2 somefile.py`

Answer (score 1):

You can install python3, and change the interpreter in VS Code to be whatever version that you want, so 2.7 or 3.x

Comment: Yes, I think I just figured this out! Is it just switching the Kernel to which ever version I need to use?

Comment: Yes, it is. That is what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Python 2 and Python 3 are very similar, and you can delete python 2 and install python 3. Then reformat your code a little.